# Unable to submit iOS app for review - "There are one or more errors on the page."

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I wanted to submit my app for the App Store on iTunes Connect, but whatever I do I got this last message telling me there are still one or more errors on the page.

> There are one or more errors on the page.

Unlike earlier errors this error does not focus on a particular place on page, nor are there any red-colored fields.

Things I did:

- filled app info
- filled contact info
- uploaded screenshots for all supported sizes
- uploaded binary / selected on iTunes Connect
- filled rating form.

Here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the message?

Comment: You should contact developer relations: https://developer.apple.com/contact/

Comment: The problem is that the error is not on this page as said, it is in the product price page and therefore can not highlight the field. Go to price tab and set your product price ;). Thanks to @pravat-mujah-maskey

Comment: I am also facing same issue in my case Built option is getting red but I upload was successful from xcode

Comment: I was able to resolve this by going to the "Pricing" tab and disabling the pre-order option for the app, and then going back to the main app version tab and changing the release schedule to manual. After submitting the app for review I was able to go back and re-enable pre-order.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If there are no errors and it just say, "`There are one or more errors on page`"

following can be solution.

Click on "Pricing" tab

and choose `Price Tier` as `Free` or `your price`

and go to your app again and Submit,
Cheers.

Answer (score 45):

Maybe you just forget the other Screenshots in the new Itunes Connect.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 32):

You need to go into your "Media Manage" in itunes connect, and tick "Use 5.5inch display" for all the empty screenshot sizes. Do the same for iPad.

Hope this helps.

[image: itunes connect]

Answer (score 31):

#### Age Rating

In my case it was "Age Rating" which is under General App Information:

[image: Age Rating - No Age Rating]

You should add an age rating before submitting:

[image]

Answer (score 29):

Adding onto this list so other people troubleshooting have something to try. For me, I had my Secondary category set to "Magazines & Newspapers" and setting it back to default "Secondary (optional)" let the app through to review with no problems.

Answer (score 9):

I was having this same issue and I literally tried all the above answers! I even tried submitting a new build thinking that might me the issue. But still it was showing the same error.

I contacted Apple Developer support multiple times and finally in the end I received a reply from them.

[image]

So there you go. This was my issue. And there was no way I could have figured this out without their email. I was practically thinking about giving up putting up the app on the iOS App Store.

Answer (score 7):

You should inspect the response from the apple server. The response contains a JSON. Search for "errorKeys", where it is not null or []. This way, you can find out the exact problem.

In my case it was saying "You must choose a version release option.", basically I needed to checkoff the pre-order option to expose the UI to select "Manually Release" option. After I selected that option, I checked back the pre-order option. This resolved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Well, even after selecting price the error didn't go away, at the end I witnessed it was because I selected Magazines and Newspapers as a category in the App information tab, which might require some additional information.
After changing it back to some other category the error goes away and I submitted Application successfully

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue i.e there are one or more errors on the page... and no indication what error is there. Finally I resolved it by traversing each option above. Though all i set was "Pricing" and as my app was free so i checked that option. Then i came back to the first tab and hit submit, and it worked, with no error.

Comment: I don't understand what you did

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue and for me the solution was to go into the media manager and tick all the "Same as 5.5" screenshot check boxes.
I only uploaded 5.5" screenshots.
No IPad but I assume if you support iPad the same applies there.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the last screenshots tab was not visible because of browser scale
[image]

So when I make zoom smaller it becomes visible
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I fix the issue by adding a cover art. scroll down at the screenshot page and upload the cover art.

[image: I fix the issue by adding a cover art. scroll down at the screenshot page and upload the cover art]

Answer (score 2):

For me there were 2 languages got selected and removed a one while keeping the default.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me there was an extra language listed. However, in the drop-down list it was blank and there was no error indicating a problem. So it was hard to catch. Check out the screenshot. Once I deleted it is said the language was "Flemish" which I never even heard of.[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me there was a tiny red Edit button for Rating in the bottom of the version tab. If you didnt answer questions to get the rating, you need to scroll down and fill that out.

Answer (score 2):

it happened with me also what worked with me was increasing the the date of preorder availability

Answer (score 2):

For me this thread helped:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115663

The answer:

> I faced the same issue few days ago on my new App, in my case, after investigation Apple Team found out that I choosed “Magazines & Newspaper” category for the app, or if I am using the Newsstand plist key. If so, then the app must include an auto-renewable subscription.
>
> Then after I unselect the secondary category in App Information Tab, I managed to submit for review without error.

Answer (score 1):

My case was different when trying to submit a Newsstand app with an in-app purchase. Under the versions tab, I had to go to the in-app purchases section (NOT the in-app purchases tab) and add the free subscription I had configured to my build submission.

Answer (score 1):

I had uploaded a new app v1.0 which got rejected. I updated the version to 1.0.1 in the plist and selected the correct version on App Store Connect. The problem I had was that my original app version was manually still listed as 1.0.

Changing that to 1.0.1 solved my problem.

Comment: Nice, It worked. I really don't understand why it was showing "There are one or more errors on the page." When I was using version 1.1

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error message didn't tell which field was missing. I got into the Console and found the 404 request, got into the response and found out that the Copyright field was missing:

[image: Response from Apple API]

Filled the field and I was able to send my app for review.

Answer (score -1):

for my case remove all character like that <======>====== from description