# "There are one or more errors on page." on application submission

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have this message when submit app to apple store: "There are one or more errors on page.", I checked all information that I filled for app, and also chose price for app, but still was success.

I researched at [Unable to submit iOS app for review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489438/unable-to-submit-ios-app-for-review), and I did as this help, but can't submit.

Comment: Maybe a screenshot of the situation would help?

Comment: Try scrolling to the bottom. The fields causing the error should be red or have an explanation.

Comment: Give us a full screenshot of your page with the scrollable area

Comment: @JesperSchläger, screenshot as: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wOaG0.png

Comment: @Eimantas: I scrolled down to check, but not seen any red error message

Comment: Are you using Safari? ;)

Comment: @flexaddicted: I used both Safari and Chrome

Answer (score 45):

If you've added or changed screenshots and you get this error, try this:

Click the `Media Manager` link in the `App Preview and Screenshots` section. In Media Manager, check all the checkboxes. Save, go back, then `Submit for Review`.

Comment: Amazing. Ended a 45 minute search for me. Thanks!

Comment: I spent an hour helplessly refreshing the page and trying to submit until I came across this. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you. And SHAME on Apple for, in my case, "one or more errors" with a white exclamation mark in a red circle next to my base language in the upper right hand corner of the screen. Who would have known where to look?

Comment: I am not seeing any check boxes in Media Manager, has anything changed recently?

Answer (score 13):

Check out the following points:

1. Check `Pricing` Tab. Select price tier or make the app free.
2. Select `Category` and `Subcategory`. You can find these fields under the App Icon field.
3. Select `Age Rating`.
4. Check other localizations except for default.

Answer (score 9):

Wow, Itunes Connect never ceases to amaze me.

I was getting "There are one or more errors on page"

The only thing I could find was a little red exclamation point next to the "English (U.S.) Primary Language" in the VERY FIRST drop down.

This is a bug, nothing is wrong with the languages it has to do with you missing the right size of screenshots.

Click on the blue "View All Sizes in Media Manager" link and click all the little boxes on the right (ex. Use 5.5" Display) to reuse your images for every size. DON'T FORGET to click over to the " iMessage App" tab as well (this is what I overlooked)

Click save, and then submit again.

I hope Apple really takes an Itunes Connect redesign seriously. Possibly the most buggy product they have made to date.

Comment: Thanks, this the exact issue I faced.

Answer (score 2):

Mine showed "There are one or more errors on page" and the "English (U.S.) Primary Language" had the error symbol.

Turns out that I didn't have screenshots loaded for 4 and 3.5 inch displays.   I simply selected the option to use screenshots from the 4.7 display and my error went away.

Answer (score 1):

Set valid price tier (I set it for free) under "Rights and Pricing" tab. Save and submit. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If English Language has the error symbol next to it, check Media Manager and make sure you have screenshots set for all supported devices.

Answer (score 1):

I've just wasted a few hours on a similar issue. No matter what size screenshots I uploaded, it wouldn't Save in Chrome. I eventually tried the same thing in Safari and it saved the first time. So, one possible workaround is to use a different browser.

Comment: I was able to upload images using chrome but getting same error and there is red mark for Build !  all uploaded builds list should be displayed and need to select from those but build is showing no + symbol and when tried to upload using app-loader or xcode it says build already there

Comment: If I click Validate in Xcode while creating Archive and it's successful and furthermore when I click upload to app-store and it's say uploaded  successfully does this mean that all my code signing and build steps are right ?

Answer (score -1):

finally after waste my 3-4 hours i got the solution of "There are one or more errors on page, and error is shown in English(U.S) primary language" in my case.. i'm unable to post the screenshots for 5.5inch screen. The reason is "safari" the default browser of mac does not support post screenshot method in my case then i download chrome there are options available to post screenshots after this submit for review button clicks...

Answer (score -2):

Tried all of the above. The only thing that worked for me was:

- Remove the build
- Remove all your screenshots
- Click `Save`
- Add all the screenshots again
- Add the same build again
- Click `Save`
- Click `Submit For Review`