# Itunes Connect can't submit due to language error

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

[image]
[Thats all it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aZm8.png)

---

I'm not sure whats wrong has it doesn't tell me.

[image]
[it shows its linked to the language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfsZk.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I met the similiar situation yesterday, I thought that's result from the iTunes connect update August 8 2016, red exclamation by all localized language without others information. If you meet this situation from August 8 2016, maybe it's the case.

I contacted Apple support and finally submitted new version since I filled up screen-shots for all sizes.

while you can upload the maximum size screenshot and 're-use' it for smaller size at 'Media Manager' page.

Comment: Thanks yeah, by filling all the screen shots it now works, thank you

Comment: this is corrrrrrrrect! why apple does not fix?

Answer (score 15):

Solution: I had the same problem. With the new update, there is a Media Manager beneath the screen shots. Even though it is giving you a Language error, the problem is with the screen shots. Simply open the media manager and make sure that every size either has its own image or you can click the checkbox to use the two required sizes. That fixed my Language error issue.

Comment: Worked for me. As I understood, screenshots may be different for every localization, so they are related to selected language (localization).

Answer (score 1):

When I update the version of my App, also encountered the same situation. After trying various methods, the solution is found.

1. upload a screenshot of the non-primary language,
   [image]
2. change the primary language,
   [image]
3. modify the non-primary language screenshot,
4. change back the primary language.

Yeah Succeed!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you choose screenshots, don't use 5.5 inch one for 3.5 screens. 
Make sure this is unchecked.

It will work after you uncheck it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Click on `Pricing` tab and choose `Price Tier` as `Free` or `<your_price>`

Otherwise check `Rating` if it is set properly.

Eventually check if you selected some extra languages to localize (even if I don't think so looking at your images)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the pricing is free and the age rating is 4+ which i believe is set properly. unfortunately it didn't work. Wish Apple made it a bit clearer.

Comment: @ChrisLehrer can you check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31734829/5109911 ? It is very strange but maybe it is your problem

Comment: If my last comment doesn't help you I suggest contacting the support at https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php since it could be a temporary bug on itunes connect. This guy has your same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843913/unable-to-submit-app-update-for-review-there-are-one-or-more-errors-on-the-page so maybe you could contact the support.