# App store submission error on Language/Localized

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

As shown in the following image, I correct all the other issues with only this left. Not quite sure how to fix it? I only have one primary language.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Itunes Connect can't submit due to language error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878676/itunes-connect-cant-submit-due-to-language-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the answer to this question here:

[iOS app submission error - localization related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929345/ios-app-submission-error-localization-related-issue)

"...When you choose screenshots, don't use 5.5 inch one for 3.5 screens. Make sure this is unchecked.

It will work after you uncheck it."

Answer (score 0):

In My case, the iPad Pro 12.9 3rd gen screenshots were required (before this time it was optional).

After **I've added iPad screenshots** issue was resolved.