# "There are one or more errors on the page." on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload a new iOS app version on iTunes Connect and am continuously getting the error

> There are one or more errors on the page.

It is highlighting the language: "English (U.S.)":

[image: There are one or more errors on the page]

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: I am also facing same issue in my case Built option is getting red but I upload was successful from xcode

Comment: Marked answer worked for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to submit iOS app for review - "There are one or more errors on the page."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489438/unable-to-submit-ios-app-for-review-there-are-one-or-more-errors-on-the-page)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**In short, had to add all images to "App Preview and Screenshots".**
I just had this issue, and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38887524/795114 answer helped me to resolve it.
Not sure why, but when removed other images and left only biggest for iPhone and iPad, this issue appeared. Seems almost like iTunes Connect bug.

**Update**
Now it worked for me. Successfully published new release by resubmitting all new images.
For more clarity, few steps:

1. Firstly deleting all images
2. Then enable "Use 5.5-Inch Display" (as also mentioned by *Mashhadi*)
3. Upload 5.5-Inch iPhone (and/or 12.9-Inch for iPad) images and press save

Comment: me too getting this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932680/there-are-one-or-more-errors-on-the-page

Comment: I can confirm this.   I was missing an image for 4.7 inch screen. I clicked the box saying "use 5.5 inch image" and this fixed it for me.

Comment: Same issue of screenshot upload function, thanks a lot!

Comment: It is solved by deleting all images, adding again all images and then set enable "Use 5.5-Inch Display" check.

Comment: add all the images fixed it for me.

Comment: This is also true for iPad Apps... You can add screenshots for iPad Mini or use the ones from the biggest screen...