# Getting error in itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store

When i am  submitting to the review in appstore getting error like this. Previously everything is fine,but recently iam facing this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple added new screenshot requirements recently. Make sure you aren't missing sizes for an iPad Pro.

Comment: yes, i added 2048x2732(12.9 inch) screen shots for ipad...but still getting error. Is this error related for Localized language?

Comment: i missed selecting the option for using 12.9 inch screens in all ipod device. Tq quelleck ,now it is fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into your "Media Manage" in itunes connect, and tick "Use 5.5inch display" for all the empty screenshot sizes. Do the same for iPad. This was answered

-

[Unable to submit iOS app for review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489438/unable-to-submit-ios-app-for-review/39008633#39008633)