# iTunes connect - must be uploaded directly

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iosdeployment

I've recently finished development on an app and have reached the point of deploying it to the store via iTunes Connect. I had managed to fill out all the required information under "App information", and "Pricing and Availability".

However my issue is i am currently stuck on the "Prepare for Submission" section. I have managed to upload screenshots and select a build. But it will not allow me to save, so essentially any edits under this section are impossible now due to the below error i am receiving:

> *"Screenshots and app previews for the largest display sizes of your app’s primary localization must be uploaded directly., Screenshots and app previews for the largest display sizes of your app’s primary localization must be uploaded directly."*

The above seemed to only occur after switching localisation to English(U.K) and then uploading my screenshots, after i saved those last amends this is when the error started occurring. However i am unable to revert any changes due to the above error.

I apologise if i'm missing something obvious here, but looking through iTunes Connect documentation and scouring the internet has came up with nothing.

Comment: It's an ongoing issue in iTunesConnect.

Comment: Same problem here... we are able to upload Dutch screenshots and submit the apps. But at the moment when I select UK I'm receiving the same annoying error message.

Comment: I see. Thank you for confirming my suspicions! I was unable to find any notice about this problem from either Apple or iTunes. Does anyone know if they've provided any further information in regards to this issue, or an ETA on a fix?

Comment: Tools like https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/deliver (CLI, if you have automatic deployment) or https://transporterapp.io (if you prefer an UI) seem to work for most people.

Comment: We use fastlane and the error started from there. After that I tried iTunes Connect, but no succes. It is still not working.

Comment: @DanJ Is your app also for iPads? If so check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009801/getting-error-in-itunes-connect

Comment: Nope. But thank you for the suggestion! It is well worth knowing.

Comment: Is there any progress with it? Apple is aware of it? Because I'm going to publish app for my client and I stuck in same spot.

Comment: @Dudi me too, been having this issue for 2 days and our app is stuck completely

Comment: @SergiusGee It appear that issue is fixed.

Comment: I can confirm as well that the issue has been fixed. Finally!
I tried to contact Apple, but all you receive back from them is some kind of template mail that is useless (i tried to post it here, but it go deleted by Stackoverflow members).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted two videos of the issue, one via Safari and the other via CLI tool deliver. The last response i had from Apple was that they were escalating the issue to their engineering team.

I've tried to edit my submission today ( 24/08/2016 ) and can confirm that the issue seems to of been resolved. I have had no response from Apple, but so far it seems to be working as intended.

Comment: I actually made a phone call to the developer program support, I made a video as well, they made a screenshare with me, they gave me a ticket number, and called me a few days later lating me know that they fixed it